# AppCompat ProgressBar height

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-xml, android-appcompat, android-progressbar

How to change the height of AppCompat `ProgressBar`?
I try with this, but no result

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="60"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:maxHeight="20dp"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/pbarbg"
    android:theme="@style/LinearProgress" />
```

And in LinearProgress style I have

```
<style name="LinearProgress" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/pbaractive</item>
</style>
```

Comment: it doesn't change the height of my progress it changes only the height of widget

Comment: You want to change the width of the ring?

Comment: you can use librarie https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`setScaleY()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleY(float)) method, to scale your `ProgressBar` in *Y-axis*.

eg: `yourProgressBar.setScaleY(2f);`

Comment: That will generate different heights depending on the Android version